# Two way communication between WebRoles & Windows CE

Tags: c#, azure, windows-ce, azure-web-app-service

We're implementing an IoT scenario where industrial components and can be controlled from internet. These components are connected to Windows CE devices, which in turn are connected to the internet using GPRS.

We want to provide an interface to control these components from the internet. We are currently using Azure Websites to host the UI. The website needs to send a request to Windows CE device and needs to get a response back with some parameters.

We are currently exploring whether Windows Sockets can be used for this. Is there a better way to communicate from Azure Websites to Windows CE using internet?

Comment: Sockets provide just the basic layer or connectivity, no security etc. Azure service bus supports Https and AMQP natively. There are no official MS SDKs (as for Linux, Android etc.), but you can find some libraries.

Comment: Thanks @ValterMinute, we're already trying to use AMQP to connect with the Service Bus using the Apache Proton C library. However, for our requirements, we would need to use Service Bus relays, which would require hosting a service inside Windows CE device. I'm still searching for documentation on Service Bus Relay requirements for hosting non-WCF service. Will keep posted once I get further details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in this scenario a better solution could be to use Azure Service Bus via HTTPS or AMQPS (as Valter said) implementing "command" IoT communication pattern thanks to the correlation between request and response on both messages and queues (see MessageId, CorrelationId and ReplyTo).

Paolo.